# How to generated a timestamp based on another formatted timestamp

Tags: powershell, datetime

I'm attempting to output a timestamp in Powershell to represent the time now (rounded down to the 00 seconds), and another to represent 30 minutes before that. Both timestamps should be formatted `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`.

If I use just Get-Date as when setting `$end_time`, then `$start_time` is set too.

```
$end_time = Get-Date
$start_time = $end_time.AddMinutes(-30)
```

However, when I format `$end_time` as required, an error occurs when settings `$start_time`.  It looks like calling `-Format` returns the date as string rather than a date object.

```
$end_time = Get-Date -Format s -Second 00
$start_time = $end_time.AddMinutes(-30)
```

> Method invocation failed because [System.String] does not contain a method 
>   named 'addminutes'.

To try and work around this shortcomming I added a `$date` variable, but now I'm unable to even set `$end_time`.  I guess this is because the formatting is returned by the Get-Date function, and cannot be set retrospectily.

```
$date = Get-Date
$end_time = $date -Format s -Second 00
```

> Unexpected token '-Format' in expression or statement.

So my question is: if I am unable to manipulate a formatted date, and if I cannot format a pre-generated date as requred, how is it possible to generate two timestamps that are 30 minutes apart (one for 'now', one for 30 minutes ago) and which are formatted as `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`?

Comment: `[datetime]$end_time = Get-Date -Format s -Second 00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `-Format` parameter of `Get-Date`, use the `.ToString` method on the date objects you create instead:

```
$Date = Get-Date -Second 0
$Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
$Date.AddMinutes(-30).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
```

**Explanation:**

- Get-Date is executed and returns a DateTime object representing the current date and time with the seconds set to 0. This is then cast to a string using the .ToString method to format per your custom style.
- The next command is the same, but before casting it as a formatted string (whereby it loses the date object methods), the `.AddMinutes` method is used to remove 30 minutes.

Comment: As I'm rounding down to the nearest minute, the danger here is that (however unlikely) the minute could tick over inbetween the two commands, meaning that the timings would only actually be 29 minutes apart (or 31 if they are switched around).  Thanks.

Comment: Ah ha, adding `$date = Get-Date` and then swapping out `(Get-Date)` for my new `$date` variable seems to do the trick.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry I missed that requirement, you can use the `-Second` parameter to do the rounding first within the brackets as now shown above.

Comment: Oh I see what you meant. Yeah using a $date variable is the right approach then.

Comment: Oh, and the format should be `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"`. Using `mm` in the date part is currently outputting the minutes, it should be 'MM'. And `hh` is for the 12-hour clock as opposed to the 24-hour clock.

Comment: I will correct in the interests of future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Keep `$date` as `datetime`, use `ToString` as required:

```
$date       = Get-date -second 0
$end_time   = $date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
$start_time = ($date.AddMinutes(-30)).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: As mentioned above, the format should be `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"`, but other than that it does the trick.